# zurb foundation.min.js and jquery.1.7.1.min.js conflicting

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I have written the code below, in which I use ZURB foundation.min.js and jquery.1.7.1.min.js together. However, my ZURB framework's drop down is not working if I use jquery.1.7.1.min.js and if I use both my image slider is not working. I think the two are conflicting, but I might not be calling them in a proper sequence. How can I resolve this issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="files/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
        <link href="files/banner.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="All">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="files/tooltip.js" language="javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="files/jquery-effects-core-slide.js" language="javascript">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="files/jquery-ui-core-widget-mouse.js" language="javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="files/jquery-ui-slider.js" language="javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="files/banner.js" language="javascript"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="chrome-extension://cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/style.css"><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="chrome-extension://cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/page_context.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header_container">
            <div class="row">
                <?php include"header.php" ?>
            </div>
            <div class="nav_container">
                <div class="row">
                    <?php include"menu.php" ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <?php include"banner.php" ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="padding-top:20px;">
            <?php include"homepage.php" ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="padding-top:20px;">
            <?php include"footers.php" ?>
        </div>
        <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).foundation();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try calling your 1.7.1 library inside of the body tag [below where zepto currently is] so that foundation.js is called first, then 1.7.1

Comment: Is there any error being displayed by the code inspector?